# Why is FORMAT function not recognised?

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I have executed the following query:

```
SELECT productid,
FORMAT(productid, 'd10') AS str_productid
FROM Production.Products;
```

I it is sayng that `'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`
I am using the TSQL2012 database and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express.
Can some one tell me what is wrong? The Express verssion has not included `Format` function?

Comment: probably there are problems with installation or you don't have enough access to system databases

Comment: It is possible, because I have seen that `SYSDATETIME` is not recognised too. How to fix this?

Comment: what does this select compatibility_level, name from sys.databases command output?

Comment: 90 = SQL Server 2005 , try to adjust compatibility level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

[here are details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb510680.aspx)

Comment: It does not allow that, the maximum is 90, is there another method? Reinstalling or something like this?

Comment: I have found it: I was connected on an old server. Just switch the servers and it is ok.